# CLSQL symbol exports

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clsql

Does anyone know about how the clsql-sys methods get exported to the clsql-sys/cl-user package?

The methods are defined individually for each database type.
For example, suppose I define a method in db-mysql/mysql-sql.lisp in package clsql-mysql:

```
(defpackage #:clsql-mysql
(:use #:common-lisp #:clsql-sys #:mysql #:clsql-uffi)
(:export #:mysql-database)
(:documentation "This is the CLSQL interface to MySQL."))
(in-package #:clsql-mysql)
(defmethod example ((database mysql-database)))
```

How do I get that method "example" into the clsql-sys package?

Sorry this question is very CLSQL specific...

thanks!
Jieren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you mean is the exports list in `mysql-package.lisp`.